# Vim versions, differences

Tags: linux, vim, fedora

Which vim version i should be use in fedora for "daily" use(shell, c,...)?
What is the differences beetween versions, types(example gvim, x11,vimrc)?

Thanks for the answers,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Vim` works in your terminal, doesn't work outside it, while `GVim` works outside the terminal as an X11 client.

`X11` is a protocol for handling graphical capabilities on linux. It doesn't have much to do with G/Vim other than rendering it on the screen (That said, you can see the differences for yourself by pressing `ctrl + alt + f<num>` and starting a `tty` session. You can get back to graphics by doing `ctrl + alt + f6` if I recall correctly).

`vimrc` is your Vim settings file. Settings edited here will be available for `Vim` and `GVim` to use after a restart or a reload. However, there are some things that will be available in `Gvim` that won't be on `Vim`, mostly relating to graphics.

For daily use, I would suggest you use `GVim` (don't forget to run `vimtutor` first!). However, if you're in your terminal a lot, consider giving `Vim` a shot instead. Also consider taking a look at the [SU Vim tag](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/vim?sort=votes&pagesize=15), [SO Vim tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vim) and [SF vim tag](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/vim?sort=votes&pagesize=50), so you can get explanations as to why some things work, and learn yourself how to be more productive when using Vim.

Also consider [VimUniversity](http://vimuniversity.com/), and googling around for how to do things in Vim. You will be surprised.

Comment: Debian has `ctrl+alt+f7`, but fedora might be different.

Comment: X is usually on `CTRL+ALT+F1` on Fedora. `systemd` dynamically creates TTYs on the fly, so graphical logins get VT1, if you press `CTRL+ALT+F2` a text terminal is automatically spawned on VT2, and if you went back to the VT1 and selected *Switch User* the new graphical session would get VT3.  Also, make sure you have the `vim-enhanced` package installed if you use Vim on Fedora (`gvim` might drag that in automatically).  Most live media spins only include the minimal Vim to save space.